# jquery change multipele variables at the same time

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change multipele variables at the same time, but haven't found a way to do it currently. The code that I have currently looks like this

```
search = $("#search"),
drop = $("#drop");
search.prop("disabled", true).css("display","none");
drop.prop("disabled", true).css("display","none");
```

But I want to set those two variables on the same line if that is possible without making them into one variable

Comment: add a class to both variable and access them with that class . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#search,#drop").prop("disabled", true).css("display","none");
```

Though, you can also do it this way;

```
$("#search,#drop").prop("disabled", true);
$("#search,#drop").css("display","none");
```

Comment: Why would you want to do the latter?

Comment: Good question. I'd gotten into that habit because I encountered some issues in the past with JQ returning the wrong object. The former is the right way of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use [multiple selector elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_sel.asp). You can also play with `hide()`/`show()` methods instead of css display none:

```
$("#search, #drop").prop("disabled", true).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using multiselector in jquery

[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
$("#search, #drop").prop("disabled", true).css("display","none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="search">Search</p>
<p id="drop">Drop</p>
<p>hi</p>
```